# Cannot create auto-configurable library for Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I am trying to do something that seems to be really simple. But I cannot get it to work somehow. There is something I must be missing.

I have 2 Spring Boot (3.0.5) projects:

- one is a lib called spring-lib
- the other is a web application that uses the lib

In my lib I have this configuration class in the package `com.example.springlib.configuration`:

```java
@Configuration
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "com.example.hello")
public class HelloConfiguration {

    private String text;

    @Bean
    public HelloService helloService() {
        return new HelloService(text);
    }
}
```

And I have this service in `com.example.springlib.service`:

```java
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class HelloService {

    private final String hello;

    public String hello(String name) {
        return String.format(hello, name);
    }
}
```

In the `META-INF/spring.factories` file, I have this:

```
org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.EnableAutoConfiguration=com.example.springlib.configuration.HelloConfiguration
```

Now In my web app, I have this controller in `com.example.springweb.web`:

```java
@RestController
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class HelloController {

    private final HelloService helloService;

    @GetMapping("/hello/{name}")
    public HelloResponse convert(@PathVariable String name) {
        var response = new HelloResponse();
        response.setMessage(helloService.hello(name));
        return response;
    }
}
```

And this `application.yml` file:

```yaml
com:
  example:
    hello:
      text: Hello %s!
```

So there is nothing too complicated here. I was expecting the service to return "Hello Bob!" if I called `/hello/Bob`.

But I cannot start the web application. For some reason, the `HelloService` cannot be found. I get this error message:

```
Description:

Parameter 0 of constructor in com.example.springweb.web.HelloController required a bean of type 'com.example.springlib.service.HelloService' that could not be found.
```

What am I missing? What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Spring Boot 3, `META-INF/spring.factories` no longer supports registering auto-configurations.

You need to register your auto-configuration classes with  `META-INF/spring/org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.AutoConfiguration.imports` file.

This file should list your configuration classes, with one class name per line. For example:

```java
com.example.springlib.configuration.HelloConfiguration
com.example.springlib.configuration.SomeOtherConfiguration
```

And by the way, from Spring Boot 2.7, it is recommended to use @AutoConfiguration instead of @Configuration especially when you want to apply multiple auto-configurations in a desired order.

You can read more about this in the official doc here: [Creating Your Own Auto-configuration](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/features.html#features.developing-auto-configuration.understanding-auto-configured-beans)

Comment: Thanks. I tried that before, but I had the same result. So I reverted back to `spring.factories`, because I could find more examples with this. But you made me realized that I was misplacing the file. I never noticed there was a `spring` folder after `META-INF`. And now it works. :S Thanks!

Comment: Nice! Glad that I was able to help.

Answer (score 0):

You can just remove the line

```
org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.EnableAutoConfiguration=com.example.springlib.configuration.HelloConfiguration
```

if still it doesn't work just add

```
@EnableAutoConfiguration
```

above your main class